# Create relation hasMany() with composite field

Tags: yii, yii2

Have the relation in model **Product** :

```
public function getDiscount()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Discount::className(), ['id' => 'available_discount']);
}
```

Model has field **available_discount**, that stores data as **1;2;3**, where **1;2;3** is discount ids.

Query `Product::find()->joinWith('discount d')->where(['d.id' => [1,2,3]])->all()`return **products** with key **discount** = [].

How i can return discounts as relation with **ID** **1, 2, 3** ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public function getDiscounts()
{
    $idsAsArray = explode(';', $this->available_discount);
    $query = Discount::find()->where(['id' => $idsAsArray]);
    $query->multiple = true;
    return $query;
}
```

And then get them via:

```
$product->discounts; // returns Discount[]
$product->getDiscounts()->count(); // gets the count of discount models.
```

Comment: Note that this is not a real relation, you cannot use it for eager loading or joins. But this is probably the best what you can get with OP 's scheme.